# Can't instantiate Spring bean repository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, model-view-controller, javabeans

In this task I am not allowed to use auto-wiring

so I am trying to create something similar to this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

My code

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public FoodService foodService() {
        return new FoodService(FoodRepository());
    }

    @Bean
    public FoodRepository foodRepository() {
        return new FoodRepository();
    }
}
```

Of course since FoodRepository is an interface extending MongoRepository, it gives an error that it has not been instantiated, and for sure inside the service I need to be calling the Repository to save and such. How to solve this?

Comment: Have you used @Repository anotation in FoodRepository?

Comment: It was missing, I added it now, but still the same issue cannot instantiate

Comment: surely you mean `return new FoodService(foodRepository());`

Comment: yes I forgot the () in the snippet, edited now

Comment: Can you provide the stackTrace

Comment: This is syntax error in the IDE before even running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in [Spring Data MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.standalone)

Inside ApplicationConfig.java I should have done the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.food.repository")
public class ApplicationConfig {
@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
private String mongoHost;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
private int mongoPort;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
private String mongoDB;

@Bean
public foodService foodService() {
    MongoOperations operations = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(mongoHost,mongoPort), mongoDB);
    MongoRepositoryFactory factory = new MongoRepositoryFactory(operations);
    foodRepository foodRepository = factory.getRepository(foodRepository.class);
    return new foodService(foodRepository);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** belog the line

Since you didn't tag the question with `Spring Boot`, I'll assume you are using vanilla `Spring`.

According to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html you would need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

  <mongo:mongo id="mongo" />

  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg value="databaseName" />
  </bean>

  <mongo:repositories base-package="com.acme.*.repositories" />

</beans>
```

I would suggest to create a similar file and include `@Import` with a reference to the .xml file in `ApplicationConfig`.

If you are not adding additional method to the `FoodRepository` interface there is no need to implement it and thus you cannot do `new FoodRepository()`.

---

Updated:

Since this is a `Spring Boot` app you would only need:

Add dependency to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Annotate main class (or `@Configuration`-annotated class) with `@EnableMongoRepositories`

Configuration properties with:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.port=
spring.data.mongodb.database=
```

Comment: but how do I inject my repository into the GeneticsService without autowiring

Comment: When using `Spring Boot`, a highly opinionated framework that creates and wires beans for you, why wouldn't you use it to your advantage? 
Do you think it would be better for your group to duplicate half of the `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` now dealing with all the wiring up to the `MongoTemplate` instead of using `... FoodService foodService(@Autowired FoodRepository foodRepository) {`.
The problem here is not the wiring, it's lack of trust to engineers or lack of knowledge or ..... resulting in `I am not allowed to use ...`

Comment: Regardless of what I think, I'm applying somewhere and this is their preference. Personally I'd go for auotwired over this option but maybe they are testing my capabilities you know? I mean autowiring is very simple compared to manually configuring the whole thing. Anyways check my answer, I found a solution

Comment: I had the chance after completing the task to talk to them. My guess was that their production application is big in terms of the number of classes and dependencies and that they needed one Java class to be able to track which classes depend on others as Autowired does not give you the chance to track something like that, and that they are actually using this way to manually track everything.

Comment: Wouldn't `/beans` Spring Boot actuator endpoint provide that?